# Form Action - Custom URL

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, themes, wordpress-theming

I have a search form in my wordpress theme. I want a custom url in search results.

My source code:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" onblur="if (value =='') {value = 'Search'}" onfocus="if (value == 'Search') {value =''}" value="Search" />
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( '', 'themevb' ); ?>" />
</form>
```

My actual search url:

```
http://www.example.com/?s=keyword&submit=
```

I need this url:

```
http://www.example.com/web/keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution, enqueue this script, or just put below the search form, it will navigate to a custom search page.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $( '#searchform' ).on( 'submit', function() {
        window.location = "http://www.example.com/web/" + encodeURIComponent( $(this).find( '#s' ).val() );
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Add custom rewrite rule, remember to flush rules by visiting the `settings->permalinks` tab in admin section.

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'web/(.+?)/?$','index.php?s=$matches[1]' );
```